# How to access Spring controller's JSON parameter?

Tags: java, json, spring

I have a Spring controller which maps me JSON to some DTO object via message converter:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"bar"},
            consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void foo(@RequestBody paramsDTO httpParams) {
        // some logic here
    }
```

Let's imagine, my DTO looks like:

```
   public class paramsDTO {
       String name;
       String surName;
   }
```

Is it possible to get access to `name` or `surName` values via some Servlet or Spring context (not directly from field)? I'm looking for something similar to `HttpServletRequest#getParameterValues()` but for the Spring JSON converter.

Comment: Why don't you want to use directly the method parameter httpParams? What are your trying to achieve?

Comment: @bangnab i need to access param value from some Spring aspect, and creating new relations beetwen components is undesirable, while there is default Spring context